# iOS 14 UIPageControl unselected page are treated as currentPage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios14, uipagecontrol

When I use setIndicatorImage to set image for the UIPageControl, unselected page's tint color are set to the currentPageIndicatorTintColor, but current page's tint color is default indicator tint color.

[image]

```
    self.customPageControl.currentPage = currentPage;
    
    if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
        _pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        _pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        for(int i=0; i<self.pageControl.numberOfPages; i++){
            if(i == currentPage){
                [self.pageControl setIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pageCtrlSelected"] forPage:i];
            }
            else{
                [self.pageControl setIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pageCtrlUnselect"] forPage:i];
            }
        }
        
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved this by call set current page after set indicator image loop. The code snipper is like below.

```
if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
    _pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    for(int i=0; i<self.pageControl.numberOfPages; i++){
        if(i == currentPage){
           [self.pageControl setIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pageCtrlSelected"] forPage:i];
        }
        else{
           [self.pageControl setIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pageCtrlUnselect"] forPage:i];
        }
    }
        
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}

/// It's important that set currentPage after set indicator image !!!!
self.customPageControl.currentPage = currentPage;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This should be documented at Apple Official documentation.